# How do I build Boost when "b2" does not work

Tags: c++, boost

In theory, boost needs to be built with `b2`. In my case, with `b2 --build-dir=c:\boost\ --toolset=msvc complete stage`.

This produces a warning `the --build-dir option was specified but Jamroot at '.' specified no project id the --build-dir option will be ignored` (looks harmless) and then the fatal notice[sic] `

```
could not find main target complete
assuming it is a name of file to create.
could not find main target stage
assuming it is a name of file to create.
```

Apparently the targets have been renamed. What is the correct target to build?

Googling finds only a few hits, none on the current (1.54.0) Boost version.

Comment: Could you try using `b2 --build-dir=c:\boost\ toolset=msvc --build-type=complete stage`? I suspect the problem is due to your use of `complete`. You need to do this from the directory that contains `boost`, `doc`, `libs`, `more`, etc.

Comment: @cv_and_he: +1, looks much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recognized target names depend on the build type. Since the command line is missing `--buildtype=`, the next token `complete` is incorrectly interpreted as a target and not recognized. The next token `stage` IS a target, but is not recognized because the buildtype is not set.